# Observable in ListView binds elements incorrectly

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

In my NativeScript App there is a ListView. I want to bind an array of Observable objects to it to modify each item individually. However NativeScript seems to bind the same single item (the last item of the bound array) for every ListView item

This is my Layout:

```
<Page loaded="onPageLoaded">
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <ListView items="{{items}}">
                    <ListView.itemTemplate>
                            <Label text="{{name}}" />
                    </ListView.itemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

The ViewModel is like this:

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var observableArray = require("data/observable-array");
var viewModule = require("ui/core/view");

var items =  [
    new observableModule.Observable({name:"Item 1"}),
    new observableModule.Observable({name:"Item 2"})
];

var pageData = new observableModule.Observable();
var page;

exports.onPageLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    pageData.set("items",items);
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
};
```

I expect the ListView to display "Item 1" and "Item 2", but it shows "Item 2", "Item 2". You can see the problem in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

The current target is Android by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the way that NativeScript's Observable class defines properties (they refer to a copy of 'this' saved in the closure, and redefine the properties in the constructor, so they all end up referring to the last object's values).  The references to `that` should be changed to `this` in data/observable/observable.ts (data/observable/observable.js in the installed version).  I created a [pull request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/918) with the change.

Comment: Excellent post! Instead, instantiating the Observable with just new Observable() and then adding <newly_created_observable>.set("my_property", my_value) for each property will do.

Comment: The exceptionally helpful folks running the Nativescript project improved my pull request and merged the change into the master branch as a new pull request [#927](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/927)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
var items = new observableArray.ObservableArray([]);
var pageData = new observableModule.Observable();
var page;

exports.onPageLoaded = function(args) {
    page = args.object;
    items.push({name:"Item 1"});
    items.push({name:"Item 2"});
    pageData.set("items",items);
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
};
```

As per my knowledge observableArray is extended class of observable so you do not need to create new observable objects while creating an observable array.

Comment: Although I still don't know why my original code did not work, I can live with this solution. It just seemed like a bug to me, but I just started using NativeScript so I was not sure at all

Comment: I am not sure if this solution is what I was looking for. If I change a list item and add a new one (`items.setItem(1,{name:"new item"})`) the UI is updated. If I just modify an existing item(`var a = items.getItem(1); a.name="changed item"; items.setItem(1,a);`) the UI is NOT changed

Comment: Suppose `items` is binded to RadListview and there is another object in pageData. In this case how can i access other object inside RadListview ?